# Have stack with: fields for and nested attributes

Tags: ruby, nested-attributes, form-for

Build some simple project and stack on using accepts nested attributes + form_for.

Now i have no problem with code, all work and save, but when i uncomment accepts_nested_attributes_fori have error or my model doesnt create (i try differente variant for last 5 days, but can t build this right..). I think i have problem in controller.. My code (which works without accepted_nested_attributes).
Model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :j_project
  has_one :p_project

#  accepts_nested_attributes_for :p_project, :j_project

  validates :user_id, :title, presence: true
end
```

View:

```
= form_for(@project) do |f|
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
  = fields_for @p_project do |fa|
    = fa.label :requester
    = fa.text_field :requester
  = fields_for @j_project do |ffa|
    = ffa.label :j_login
    = ffa.text_field :j_login
    = ffa.label :j_password
    = ffa.text_field :j_password
  = f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

Controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @p_project = @project.build_p_project
    @j_project = @project.build_j_project
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.user = current_user
    @p_project = @project.build_p_project(p_project_params)
    @j_project = @project.build_j_project(j_project_params)
    if @project.save && @p_project.save && @j_project.save
      flash[:success] = "New project was added successfully"
      redirect_to user_root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title)
    end

    def p_project_params
      params.require(:p_project).permit(:requester)
    end

    def j_project_params
      params.require(:j_project).permit(:j_login, :j_password)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems was with validation:
project_id in j_project and p_project - when I dell them, all works well.
I edit my simple_form and controllers too with guides from internet... But problems, which I cant find in google - was with validation.